# Cannot install SQL Server 2008 : Previous release of VS 2008 error

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I had Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition installed in my computer. When i installed this VS 2008 version, SQL Server 2005 was also automatically installed. I just had to install SQL Management Studio

Because i want to install SQL Server 2008. I un-installed SQL Server 2005 and tried to install SQL Server 2008. But in the "Installation Rules" section in the installing setup, it prompts a message saying "Previous Release of VS 2008 Failed" (**see the image below**)

When I google it, i came to [Microsoft Support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/956139) where they say the VS Version i have must be Service Pack 1 and must be a release version (not beta version). Now I'm confused with it.

1. **What should I do?**
2. How do I find the Service Pack Version of VS 2008
3. How do I find if the version is a release or a beta one
4. I recently installed VS 2010 C# Express and Web Developer 2010 Express. Without going to SQL Server 2008 can I work with VS 2010 with SQL Server 2005?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do I find the Service Pack Version of VS 2008?
There are service packs for Visual Studio 2008 express that are different to the VS2008 standard / prof etc  service packs.

How do I find if the version is a release or a beta one? No idea.

I recently installed VS 2010 C# Express and Web Developer 2010 Express. Without going to SQL Server 2008 can I work with VS 2010 with SQL Server 2005?

Yes you can work with SQL 2005 with both of those to the best of my knowledge.

You can try uninstalling all instances of visual studio and then installing sql 2008 but that would be a last resort i would think. Trying the vs2008 express service packs would be my first step.

Rgds

AJ

Answer (score 0):

See this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/956139 and for a more detailed answer see this 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2008/08/11/sql-server-2008-visual-studio-2008-sp1-and-net-framework-3-5-sp1-explained.aspx.

I also had this issue and when I visited Microsoft site, then I found this solution and it worked.

Comment: Thanks fareed. I'll try that on